# Is number of items in`file sink` integer multiple of `sample rate`?

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

I use flow graph for `file sink` as below:
[image]
When I stop running this flow graph, there are `110000` float numbers in file `a`,with 10k per segment.
`samp rate` is `32k`,`a` should append `32k` numbers each second.

But`110000` is not integer multiple of `32k`.What's the reason?

Answer (score 4):

No — unless your code recorded for exactly a whole number of seconds, the number of samples won't be a multiple of the sample rate.

Comment: Much more succinct than my answer!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a strong relationship between the *count* of binary data in the resulting file and the sample rate.

I mean, a higher sample rate might result in more data points between segments. But I don't think you can count on a 1:1 relationship given that this sink is a buffered sink. At most, maybe you can say that *up to* some binary values will have been collected per segment based on the sample rate.

Put simply: Gnu Radio caution against assuming the binary data in these files can be used to derive anything about how the data was collected, as this is what the metadata is for.